# Is there a comparative study of the memory consumption of programming languages runtimes, correlated with expressiveness and production bug ratios?

Tags: programming-languages, performance, memory

There are many comparative studies and available online when it comes to the runtime performance of applications built using one language or another. Some driven by corporations, some academic, some just personal experiment reports.

We also get a decent share of comparative studies on side-effects of a programming language and its tooling, like:

- build times,
- likelihood of post-production bug detection,
- expressive power,
- etc...

However, I've recently been more and more bummed out by the memory consumption of my programs more than anything else. This might come from the fact that while Moore's Law is on our side for raw performance, we have come to realize that other bottlenecks matter more. That, and I don't tend to update my hardware every so often, and I have some "old" (read 2005-2006 3.6GHz Pentium 4 with 4GB of RAM) that nowadays are hard-pressed to be useable for large applications without requiring me to go through great trouble to squeeze every bit of juice out of them (choice of OS, UI, tweaking of services and daemons, choice of applications to use for a task or another...). Quite honestly, sometimes I fire up `top` or `procexp` and weep at the sight of the memory used by the most innocent programs.

I can address this by keeping to push in the direction listed above, and essentially trying to limit myself and the programs I use (I have a dear love for cli programs for that reason, I guess), but I also cannot help but to think that maybe we're doing it wrong.

#### Modern Tools for Modern Needs

Of course, higher-level languages are arguably better and justify their worth of dead weight. Some design choices were made for good (or supposedly well-intended) reasons at the time, in many toolchains. Shared libraries, memory models, pre-processors, type-systems, etc... But some might be more viable than others with our modern hardware, and I'd be curious to read a few serious studies on the matter.

So, my question is, is there a pendant to the [Benchmarks Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/) and others that focus on a comparison of the languages' base runtime memory consumption?

And even further, are there some studies that cross-reference this with other parameters (similar to what [this article](http://blog.gmarceau.qc.ca/2009/05/speed-size-and-dependability-of.html) did, for instance, for other criteria, also based on the [Benchmarks Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/))?

Comment: Why is the benchmarks game insufficient?  It's probably the best resource there is, and it already covers memory consumption in detail.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It does provide memory information, but it's not for the "base" runtime. Also, I find extracting information from the Benchmarks Game rather arcane (all the more credit for that [article](http://blog.gmarceau.qc.ca/2009/05/speed-size-and-dependability-of.html) doing an amazing job with its data, though it's not the one I seek).

Comment: It might help the people trying to answer your question if you provided some information about what problem it is that you're trying to solve, with some specifics like your execution environment and your desired memory consumption.  The answer is going to differ if you're writing software for an embedded environment (where the amount of memory used is important) versus a state-of-the-art desktop machine (where memory consumption is essentially inconsequential, unless the software system is extremely large).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: also, the benchmarks game doesn't cover memory consumption "in detail". It gives a gross figure of the used memory, but without details of the memory distribution for, say, the language's runtime, the program's compiled size, the program own runtime footprint on startup, the program's memory consumption for its used data (w/o it's own runtime consumption), etc... It's all nice, but it's not detailed enough in my opinion in that area.

Comment: Why do you need metrics that specific?  Doesn't language choice trump such considerations?  You said that you weep when you fire up certain programs.  How much memory consumption makes you weep?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Why do you need to care what they're for? I want to know them because there's not in my view any ressource that provides this information and I think it would be very helpful and could be a new axis on which to compare languages, rather than things that are less quantifiable and that we programmers often argue endlessly about. It doesn't matter much for which environment my specific problem would be: it would help people to be able to make a decision for **theirs**. But I know your question is well-intended and trying to re-center and define a scope. Just not sure it's needed.

Comment: @Dynamic: thanks for the editing help, and I know that callouts to mods aren't well-received, but I also know that duplicates are easily misidentified (there are many comparative studies on languages, but not of that kind). Also, you removed other edits which in my way made the question easier to visually parse.

Comment: I care what they're for, because, in its present form, without additional clarification, your question boils down to a resource request, and is off-topic as such.  I'm trying to get enough clarification so that your question can be adequately answered without getting closed.  Requests for links are better served by employing a major search engine, like Google.

Comment: `Doesn't language choice trump such considerations?` This is part of language choice. It's not just about syntactic sugar and spice.

Comment: The latest version of the .NET framework is just shy of 50 megabytes in size.  I challenge you to find a computer that is insufficient to support that.  Your problem is not the language; it's the requirements of the operating system, which get larger and more pronounced with each new version.  Perhaps I could interest you in an embedded version of Linux?

Comment: `How much memory consumption makes you weep?` 30MBs for an inactive Chrome tab w/o extensions, 100MB for ATI's CCC, even 11MB for an inactive googletalk plugin, or 23MB for an inactive printer driver. These things, and many more. The chrome example is a bit out of the park as it's a more complex example, but the other ones already surprise me quite a bit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: `Perhaps I could interest you in an embedded version of Linux?` No thanks, I know the topic of embedded software decently well, and that would boil down to what I evoke in my question's background: circumventing the issue by relying on less. And no, I don't want the moon or something that gets me the moon without paying any cost in return. I look for something that gives me a breakdown of that cost, for several alternatives.

Comment: But you're working in an ecosystem surrounded by bloatware, software that you don't control.  How are you going to fix that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9131/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-haylem)

Comment: @haylem Ah, I guess I must have submitted my edit at the same time as the other. Sorry about that.

Comment: Based on the discussion I've had with Robert and GlenH7 (see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9131/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-haylem)) I'll try to reword the question later. Bear with me.

Comment: "Is there a comparative study ..." etc. I've seen this kind of question before, and to my mind it reflects a common misperception - that as long as you choose the right language, you'll be making an optimal tradeoff between expressibility and performance. IME, any program that makes heavy use of memory allocation and deallocation is going to suffer badly, and that could be due to the language, and/or the way the program is written.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: to me it sounds like you have a misperception of what research is about. I don't look for definitive answers, just for interesting angles. And I'm looking at base cases here.

Comment: @haylem: well, I did enough of it myself, and as for interesting angles, [*I gave it my best shot.*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Building_Better_Applications.html?id=8A43E1UFs_YC) As a practitioner, I find what young programmers have been taught about performance is [*amazingly naive.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: darn, touché! I bow to a master. And I totally agree with your second point. But still, my point here is to look for research being conducted in this area, not to use it as a magic wand to determine which language would be a better all-purpose fit, or even a reference card for which stack or language to use. Nor do I look for a debate on the benefit of higher-level langs on productivity while trading off other things. It's more of a curiosity thing (even though it's a moving target and results may be obsoleted quickly), and I understand the gripes one may have with the question.

Comment: @haylem: I bow to an honest question. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>*I have found some partial information, so I will start to compile my findings in my own answer. Please don't let that stop you from contributing your own answers (or editing this one).*</sup>

## Existing Literature:

- *An Empirical Comparison of 7 Programming Languages* - Prechelt (2000) [[PDF](http://pinky.web.srk.fer.hr/java/usporedba.pdf)]

  A bit dated, but covers some of the material I'm interested in and does give a view of the runtime memory use and expressiveness. Results may greatly differ now, but it's an interesting start.
- *Speed, Size and Dependendability of Programming Languages* - Marceau (2009) [[blog](http://blog.gmarceau.qc.ca/2009/05/speed-size-and-dependability-of.html)]
- *Code Used, Time Used Shapes* from the *[Benchmarks Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/)* [[u32](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/code-used-time-used-shapes.php), [u32q](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32q/code-used-time-used-shapes.php), [u64](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64/code-used-time-used-shapes.php), [u64q](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/code-used-time-used-shapes.php)]

  Though it doesn't cover runtime memory consumption, Marceau's work is more or less the kind of reference or empirical study I'd be willing to find for that critera, in terms of content and quality. A good example of what I'm after, just for different metrics. The second article is a follow-up found on the Benchmarks Game site and that was published shortly after (and which references) Marceau's work, with more recent screens and more languages, though still without runtime memory details. Each graph on these pages then leads to language-to-language comparison which **do** provide high-level memory info though.

Comment: Marceau's work is an exercise in story telling, and some of the stories don't make sense -- "Does introducing functional features kill performance?" ignores the simple fact that some of those "functional language" programs might not use functional features. The data was taken from a previous incarnation of the benchmarks game; and was initially used without understanding, so there were several cycles of correction after publication (check the comments).

Comment: For your "base runtime memory consumption" a simple comparison of "hello world" programs might be as good as you need.

Comment: @igouy: yes. Not doubt on that, but I was hoping not to have to experiment and document/maintain that myself :) In fact, even less than a hello world would be OK, as in some you wouldn't even be required to link to (or load) printing routines, for instance. (disabling compiler optimizations and others things might be advisable as well)

Comment: @igouy: regarding Marceau's work, I know, I've read the page, the comments, the updated Benchmark Game pages, and been in touch with him. The article is still a good reference in my opinion. The fact that it's imperfect doesn't take away its value and it still is in the direction of what I'd like to find (or recreate myself).

Comment: "but I was hoping not to have to experiment and document/maintain that myself" -- look at the measurements in the [InternetArchive](http://web.archive.org/web/20060924085452/http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/gp4/benchmark.php?test=hello&lang=all). Unfortunately for you I decided the memory measurements for Hello World were utterly misleading and stopped displaying them after 2005.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answering the question per say, but perhaps changes the perspective a bit.  I am bearing in mind the transcript from chat, to set the tone of this answer-comment that is sure to be subject of many down votes.

There are people, hardware providers, tool providers, and programmers who are concerned about efficiency.  For the time being, it will be a growing concern for them and all of us.  Those concerns are rooted in mobile devices, particularly the high powered, battery gobbling monsters with the biggest screens and the strongest radios.

To take one more step back, part of the reason we find ourselves in the situation we are in today, with comparatively massive frameworks, and some slight disregard for general efficiency, beyond the hardware improvements is legacy.  Compatibility with legacy systems entrenches us with compatibility on top of compatibility.  It is not so much the fault of a top level run-times, as they essentially are the same runtime acting quite efficient and performant when used in a different operating environment (e.g. Xbox, windows mobile pre 7/8/surface, java micro framework, etc).

Compare the extent of the compatibility a desktop possesses with its legacy software to the extent of compatibility a mobile device possesses.

With the mobile devices, the device producers make some effort to ensure some compatibility, but they have not made compatibility a core fundament.  When the choice is between continuing to provide compatibility and moving the design of the mobile system forward, the mobile system moves forward.

For desktops, the opposite seems true.  If a significant breaking change strikes the marketers or early adopters wrongly, it pushes needed features and needed redesign to the back room many times over.  At some point I remember rumors to the effect that we as Windows users would find a completely and dramatically new file system with Windows XP, then in Vista, later the same for Seven, and finally again in Eight, but no, just incrementally improved since we first saw it on Windows2000?  The new file-system sat around for a long time, was scrapped, and however rumors decide the story after that, I cannot say.  That is probably the biggest known case, but I am positive it is not the only big case.

Even with the most recent tablets and mobile OS's, Microsoft who once shaped the market, is now intertwined in a death match with not only consumers, but a shadow of itself from the desktop department.  The tablet had to have significantly interoperability with the desktop counterpart.  No, it could not play perfectly with it, because of architecture differences, but also because of the archaic nature of the desktop underpinnings did it make significant sacrifices.

Now certainly, Windows is the easy target for any kind of criticism for this situation, but other platforms are far from "sin-free".  There are a lot of relics lurking in the Linux ecosystem that I am sure cause great consternation for systematic improvement.

Economics play a big part into this equation; how we finance our computing and applications on one, and how they are financed on the other follow astoundingly different patterns.  Where Wintel once strongly influenced obsolescence, Apple and Google have turned it into a near strict schedule.  This is further off course, than I intended, so I will leave as it sits and let the readers take it from there.

If and when big providers change their obsolescence and pricing models, then they can start to move forward with larger scale changes at a more even rate.  Those top-level frameworks that are driven by the highest order languages will shrink in a way, as they will be able to achieve their high-level task with a more low-level like efficiency because the inefficient intermediate compatibility and low-level layers will be drastically reduced, if not eliminated.

Comment: Doesn't really answer indeed, it's more like free-form thoughts adding to the bakground of the question :) Thanks and +1 for the insight, though. (Also, I want to clarify that I never intended to single out Microsoft systems as part of the culprits. Any OS as the same issue, if the system's memory model and the executable format allow it).

Comment: It certainly isn't my intent to poke at Microsoft, but they are the easiest case for most to see in this regard.  Other big name, traditional providers are in the same boat, if even in perhaps a slightly different regard (industrial grade databases and networking equipment for instance; how many compromises do they carry forward that otherwise impedes significant improvement to their underlying product innovation and value).  Even closer to home on the products each one of us supports, we carry that proverbial cross to one degree or another.